# jPane Scroll on two divs - Problems

Tags: html, jpanel

I am having problems adding jpanel in my web.

I have two divs with the same class, where  I want to add the scroll, but in the first visit to the web, it shows only 1 div with scroll.

When I refresh the web, it shows both. (Except in Chrome, where it never shows)

All needed libraries are added, and divs have the class tag.

Here comes the code:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scrollCh').jScrollPane();
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsFiddle with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is very strange, but did you try to add the reinitialize option? like

```
    var settings = {
      autoReinitialise: true
    };

    $('.scrollCh').jScrollPane(settings);
```